# Can I change the marker in a Google Maps embedded map (iframe)?

Tags: google-maps, iframe, google-maps-markers, embedded-resource

I know I can do it with the Google Maps API, but do you know if there is a way to change the marker in an embedded Google Map?

I want to replace the default "A" button for a ["B" button](http://www.ideasfestival.co.uk/wp-content/themes/ad-clerum-10/images/venues/map_icons/red_MarkerB.png) or the [marker with just a dot in the middle](http://www.fairdata2000.com/GoogleMaps/graphics/marker.png).

Comment: Are you wanting to create a custom icon? Also check here for great Google Map API References: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/

Comment: no, just change the default icon for other of the Google Maps icons. I tought perhaps you can add a parameter to the iframe URL to specify the marker.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I haven't played around with embedding Google Maps before (I generally go straight to the API for stuff like this).  I tried a couple of approaches:

- I figured maybe the embed syntax would be the same as the static maps api.  So I grabbed a static maps URL,  copied the markers param from that and tried sticking it into the iFrame URL.  This didn't work so much.
- I created a [Google  MyPlaces](http://maps.google.com/maps/myplaces?hl=en&ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=37.462243,78.662109&vpsrc=1&ctz=-660&t=v&z=4) and customized the [marker](http://www.fairdata2000.com/GoogleMaps/graphics/marker.png) to use the one your provided.  This created a [Test map](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&vps=1&jsv=168d&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=109115301202341389527.00046e1cbfbb8b2595d31) which had the appropriate marker icon.  I then grabbed the embed code and stuck it on a [test page](http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo11) and voila!

Comment: woow! ingenious! and it works for my project :)

thanks for trying different ideas and even building demos!!

Comment: Glad to hear that my solution was appropriate for your project :).

Comment: Thanks @paperjam. I can't find that question anymore, but just changed it to link to the MyPlaces page.

Comment: @RedBlueThing I wanted to see your solution, but I couldn't open the page anymore, I am trying to do something similar. I hope you can still find it.

Comment: Perhaps something changed in the google API, but the map linked to from the test page does not work.

Comment: Iframe has an advantage of not requiring Api key so for instance if you display a map tons of time as a side - it could be beneficial

Answer (score 5):

Actually I had the same problem but didn't use any of the methods above and thought I share:

If you only want a marker as I did but don't want to use API then simply fool google into thinking you want a route planned using the GET tags "saddr"  and "daddr"

"saddr" defines your start location (post code , street name+ number, whatever)

ONLY define saddr and leave out daddr and google maps will by default still show the marker for "A" (your start location) exactly where you want it , all in iframe without API.

Comment: How does this create the custom marker option for iframe maps? I you just want a Google marker on the desired location, this is not the way to go. Go to maps and search address, then click on share to create a map for that location (with marker and other usefull links like direction). This is an old answer, maybe this feature wasn't available then?

Comment: at the time no, life has gotten easier for this over the years :)