# Googlemaps custom placemark implemented within HTML embed code

Tags: html, google-maps

My goal is to add a custom placemarker to a google map via the HTML embed code they provide. Is this even possible?

We will use the following code as an example:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" 
src="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&
amp;q=Buckingham+Palace,+London,+Greater+London+SW1A+1AA,+United+Kingdom&amp;aq=&
amp;sll=54.939216,-1.599162&amp;sspn=0.810981,2.368927&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;geocode=FTTZEQMdvtX9_w&
amp;split=0&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Buckingham+Palace,+London+SW1A+1AA,+United+Kingdom&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&
amp;ll=51.501364,-0.14189&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

I realise there are better ways of doing it but I need to put this code between shortcode tags which seem to only accept this embedded HTML code in an iFrame. Although if anyone has any alternative suggestions which they think might work with shortcodes they are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has been answered here:
[Can I change the marker in a Google Maps embedded map (iframe)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175691/can-i-change-the-marker-in-a-google-maps-embedded-map-iframe#answer-1176251)

If this is about WordPress shortcodes, you could probably also find a plugin that uses Google Maps API and provides a shortcode interface and the possibility to use custom markers. This one at least claims to do that:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-map-shortcode/

Or you could even code a plugin yourself or just implement this functionality in your theme using Google Maps API and Shortcode API:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API