# Google Map on a wordpress site. Can't figure out how to put a customized icon for placemark

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

I have a wordpress website. I've embedded a map on the contacts page. How can I put a customized logo as a placemark in that map? I am fairly new to this and would like to know how to do this.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175691/can-i-change-the-marker-in-a-google-maps-embedded-map-iframe

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add a div over the map with a customized logo.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a marker to the map?
You can see the example from Snazzy Map (view source code of their example) https://snazzymaps.com/download-example/1
Then add the url of your customized icon.

```
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(-39, 700),
                map: map,
                icon: "http://yoursite.com.au/wp-content/uploads/your-marker.png",
                title: 'Anything you want!'
            });
```

I am pretty sure there are other ways, but that's how I did mine.